# I want to write a shell script to delete duplicates in a directory

Tags: shell-script, files, zsh, deduplication

I do

```
find ./ -type f -exec md5 '{}' \; > tempfile
```

`tempfile` has lines like this:

```
MD5 (.//Photos-10/IMG_20200901_183050612.jpg) = 2e1f245d195b8d2c3z926dbe0410f7b5
```

I want to check for repeated md5sums in `tempfile` and delete the second file corresponding to that hash. I am trying to do this on `zsh`. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Are you trying to do something that `fdupes` does not already do?

Comment: Totally agree with Kusalananda. If you still want to pursue this avenue, you could use `sort` by the md5 field and then, having encountered two equal md5sums in a row, you delete either file. Doing it without `sort` using `zsh` alone looks like a mammoth task.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda, I didn't know of `fdupes` before.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, thank you. Don't know why `sort` didn't occur to me. I don't intend to re-invent `fdupes`, Should I need something that `fdupes` doesn't do, I will try with `sort`.